# Convert decimal to hex/binary

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, hex, decimal

I have small math question.

Is there any way to convert decimal number (for example 3.14) to hex or binary? If it's possible, can anybody place here some links to tutorials or exaplanations?  (I don't want it for some language, I need it generally in math.) Please help.

**EDIT**:

Input passed in code:

```
0.1
```

Output in ASM code:

```
415740h
```

Another input:

```
0.058
```

Another output by compiler:

```
00415748h
```

But how has been this done? How can be it converted?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary

Comment: _I don't want it for some language, I need it generally in math._ Checkout: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Mr D - I meant numbers with comma (for example 5,21651526)

Comment: You can't convert floating point numbers to hex or binary. Just natural numbers work. It's hexadecimal (base 10-> base 16), so, if you want floating point, you had to use floating point in it aswell like FF,EA09. But nobody use it

Comment: So how double/float works? They are translated to hex by compiler. I see it in disassembled code...

Comment: Lets say, the first 16bits of a 32bit floating point variable are for the natural numbers part and 16bits for the floating part. If you want the exact method, i look for it

Comment: That `00415748h` doesn't look particularly plausible as a floating-point value.  Can you show more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recognize your output samples as encodings of floating-point numbers or other common representations of .1 and .058. I suspect these numbers are addresses where the assembler or compiler has stored the floating-point encoding.

In other words, you wrote some text that including a floating-point literal, and the assembler or compiler converted that literal to a floating-point encoding, stored it at some address, and then put the address into an instruction that loads the floating-point encoding from memory.

This hypothesis is consistent with the fact that the two numbers differ by eight. Since double-precision floating-point is commonly eight bytes, the second address (0x415748) was eight bytes beyond the first address (0x415740).

The process for encoding a number in floating-point is roughly this:

Let x be the number to be encoded.

Set s (a sign bit) to 0 if x is positive and to 1 if x is negative. Set x to the absolute value of x.

Set e (an exponent) to 0. Repeat whichever of the following is appropriate:

- If x is 2 or greater, add 1 to e and divide x by 2. Repeat until x is less than 2.
- If x is less than 1, add -1 to e and multiply x by 2. Repeat until x is at least 1.

When you are done with the above, x is at least 1 and is less than 2. Also, the original number equals (-1)<sup>s</sup>·2<sup>e</sup>·x. That is, we have represented the number with a sign bit (s), and exponent of two (e), and a significand (x) that is in [1, 2) (includes 1, excludes 2).

Set f = (x-1)·2<sup>52</sup>. Round f to the nearest integer (if it is a tie between two integers, round to the even integer). If f is now 2<sup>52</sup>, set f to 0 and add 1 to e. (This step finds the 52 bits of x that are immediately after the “decimal point“ when x is represented as a binary numeral, with rounding after the 52<sup>nd</sup> digit, and it adjusts the exponent if rounding at that position rounds x up to 2, which is out of interval where we want it.)

Add 1023 to e. This has no numerical significance with regard to x; it is simply part of the floating-point encoding. When decoding, 1023 gets subtracted.

Now, convert s, e, and f to binary numerals, using exactly one digit for s, 11 digits for e, and 52 digits for f. If necessary, including leading zeroes so that e is represented with exactly 11 binary digits and f is represented with exactly 52 binary digits. Concatenate those digits, and you have 64 bits. That is the common IEEE 754 encoding for a double-precision floating-point number.

There are some special cases: If the original number is zero, use zero for s, e, and f. (s can also be 1, to represent a special “negative zero“. If, before adding 1023, e is less than -1022, then some adjustments have to be made to get a “denormal“ result or zero, which I do not describe further at the moment. If, before adding 1023, e is more than 1023, then the magnitude of the number is too large to be represented in floating point. It can be encoded as infinity instead, by setting e (after adding 1023) to 2047 and f to zero.

Comment: 'Set x to the absolute value of x' - what did you mean?

Comment: Whatever the value of x is, take its absolute value, and change x to have that value. So, if x is -3, set it to 3. If x is 3, set it to 3 (which is no change). The purpose of this step is merely to remove the sign so that the following steps only need to deal with positive numbers. E.g., one of the following steps figures out the exponent and adjusts x to be in [1, 2). If that step had to be written to adjust positive x to be in [1, 2) and negative x to be in (-2, 1], it would be more complicated. So, in this early step, we are remembering the sign (in s) and removing it from x.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal to Floating-point:
http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/flt/dtof.html

Comment: [Here is Binary to Hex](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/convexamp/binhex.html)
You just simply need to Convert each 4 binary digits to 1HEX

Comment: It is for numbers with comma - floating point numbers. They are stored in 32 bits (or 64b for double). First bit is sign (0=+/1=-), then 8 bits of exponent (-127 - +127), and rest is normalized number (without "1,").